# How to flatten the structure of multiple collections into a single one with a common id with streams

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, java-11

Let's say that I have a list of dtos like:

```
@Builder(setterPrefix = "with")
@Data
public class ListWithDetailsRow {
    String name;
    LocalDateTime updatedAt;
    LocalDateTime createdAt;
    String customerId;
    String listId;
    String productName;
    String productId;
    Integer quantity;
    LocalDateTime addedAt;
}
```

I would like to map the above one to the:

```
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ListDetails {
    private final String name;
    private final String listId;
    private final String customerId;
    private final LocalDateTime createdAt;
    private final LocalDateTime updatedAt;
    private final List<ListProductDetails> products;
}
```

where ListProductDetails looks like:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
public class ListProductDetails {
    private final String productId;
    private final Integer quantity;
    private final LocalDateTime addedAt;
}
```

So far I have:

```
public List<ListDetails> groupListWithProductsById1(List<ListWithDetailsRow> listWithDetailsRows) {

        return listWithDetailsRows.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ListWithDetailsRow::getListId))
                .values()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .map(sl -> new ListDetails(
                        sl.getName(),
                        sl.getListId(),
                        sl.getCustomerId(),
                        sl.getCreatedAt(),
                        sl.getUpdatedAt(),
                        newArrayList(
                                new ListProductDetails(
                                        sl.getProductId(),
                                        sl.getQuantity(),
                                        sl.getAddedAt()))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but with this implementation, I am receiving List of ListDetails class
[image: structure]

but the goal is to receive List with a flattened structure of products because they have the same id group.
I know that I can flat this product structure by using:

```
listDetails.stream().flatMap(sl -> sl.getProducts().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

but I don't know how to use it properly after the `groupingBy()` operation. Will be grateful for suggestions. Cheers!

Comment: @Sweeper yes, indeed, they have common attributes, only productId's and their name will be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do:

```
public List<ListDetails> groupListWithProductsById1(List<ListWithDetailsRow> listWithDetailsRows) {
    return listWithDetailsRows.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ListWithDetailsRow::getListId)).values().stream()
        .map(rows ->
            new ListDetails(
                rows.get(0).getName(),
                rows.get(0).getListId(),
                rows.get(0).getCustomerId(),
                rows.get(0).getCreatedAt(),
                rows.get(0).getUpdatedAt(),
                rows.stream().map(row -> new ListProductDetails(
                    row.getProductId(), row.getQuantity(), row.getAddedAt()
                )).collect(Collectors.toList())
            )
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

After grouping by the list ID, you have a `Collection<List<ListWithDetailsRow>>` as the `values()` of the returned map. Each of the lists in the collection represents a group.

You can then `map` each group to a `ListDetails`. The `name`, `listId`, `customerId`, `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields of the `ListDetails` can be taken from an arbitrary element in the group (I've chosen the first one), since every element should have the same values for those fields.

For the `products` field, just `map` the `ListWithDetailsRow`s to `ListProductDetails` and collect to a list.

Comment: thanks for the answer, it's working like a charm. This `.flatMap(Collection::stream)` was redundant. Cheers!